# C Sockets: What would cause the accept function to return -1

Tags: c, sockets

Here is the code.

```
char *httpHeader = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n";

/* poll the server for requests */
int client;

for (;;) {
    client = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);

    if (send(client, httpHeader, sizeof(httpHeader), 0) < 0)
        perror("Error");
    else
        printf ("packet send done");
}
```

I know that that server is running and initialized and when I try to open it through localhost on a browser it just sits there loading but nothing happens....

Comment: You should call `perror()` if `accept()` returns `-1` to find out why.

Comment: Please read `man 2 accept` and see what kind of  errors it can produce.

Answer (score 2):

> ... and when I try to open it through localhost on a browser it just sits there loading but nothing happens ...

This is a different issue than `accept` returning -1 as claimed in the title. You simply never close the socket and you also don't send a valid HTTP response because you use `sizeof(httpHeader)` as length to sent. But `sizeof(httpHeader)` is not the length of the (slightly invalid) header but `sizeof(char*)`, i.e. you send only 8 bytes (on 64 bit).

> C Sockets: What would cause the accept function to return -1

Typically this is the case when the server socket is somehow invalid or when the client has closed the socket before `accept` returned to user space (the connection is done inside the OS kernel). Check the `errno` for details in your specific case. Note that `errno` or `perror` are only useful if `accept` actually returns -1.

Comment: after fixing some of the things you pointed out like the size of the header, and checking errno I get "Error: Invalid argument"

Comment: @comanderderp: Unfortunately you don't provide enough code to reproduce your problem. Specifically anything about `sock` as the only non-constant argument to `accept` and thus likely the cause of your problem is completely unknown. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and make sure that the code you provide make it possible to reproduce you problem and is also minimal.

Answer (score 1):

If -1 is returned by [`accept`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) or [`send`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send), `errno` is set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h)

After errno is set, call [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) or [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to find out more about what happened.

Comment: running perror for the accept I get "Error: : Undefined error: 0" and the same with send...